# Problem regarding localisation of rings.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity. Let $S$ be a multiplicatively closed set. Then show that, $S^{-1}A=0$, iff $0$ belongs to $S$?

Comment: Have you shown either direction? If so, please indicate that in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $0\in S$. Let $\frac{a_1}{s_1},\frac{a_2}{s_2}\in S^{-1}A$ be arbitrary. Set $s=0\in S$. Since $s(s_2a_1-s_1a_2)=0(s_2a_1-s_1a_2)=0$, all elements in $S^{-1}A$ must be equivalent, i.e. $S^{-1}A$ contains only a single element and thus $S^{-1}A=0$.
2. "Commutative ring with identity" means, that either $A=0$, in which case $0\in S$ trivially, because $S$ cannot be empty, or $0\neq 1$. Thus from now assume $0\neq 1$ in $A$. We have $1\in S$ - this is a standard condition for admissible multiplicative $S$ (cf. Atiyah/Macdonald: "Introduction to Commutative Algebra", p. 36). Look at the two elements in $S^{-1}A$ of the form $\frac{1}{1},\frac{0}{1}\in S^{-1}A$. Since $S^{-1}A=0$ is given, we need to have $\frac{1}{1}=\frac{0}{1}=0_{S^{-1}A}$, i.e. in $A$ we have for some $s\in S$ that $0=s(1\cdot 1- 1\cdot 0)=s\cdot 1=s$. Thus we have $0=s\in S$.

Comment: Please don't answer low quality questions like this until they've been improved. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) for more details.